# ellucian banner goamtch for c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, banner

I am currently working on a project for my university that requires api access to Ellucian Banner Oracle Packages.  I am able to insert new student records without any issues utlizing the gb_identification.p_create package/function.  However, validation occurs with GOAMTCH form on Banner.  I can't seem to find a way to call GOAMTCH to validate if there is a duplicate entry in Oracle.

If anyone has any input as to how to accomplish this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package to use GOAMTCH to verify duplicate entries is **GP_COMMON_MATCHING**.